# How to express mandatory internship to enroll to Psychologists Association

Tags: phrase-request

I have to say that I am doing an internship that is mandatory in order to be a certified psychologist, that means being a member of the Psychologists Association. Therefore what is the best way to express concisely this concept?

- "a mandatory internship to enroll in the Psychologists Association"
- "Psychologists Association mandatory internship"
- "internship prerequisite to be a certified psychologist"
- or what wlse?

I edited the post to address some comments: 
- It is for a resume.
- the connection is that certified psycologists (the ones that can work as psycologists) are the one in the Psychologists Association. the association request as mandatory an internship of at least one year and then a final exam in order to be part of it

Comment: Can you provide a little more context? Are you writing a resume? Is this casual conversation?

Comment: I see three roles here (an obligatory intern, a certified psychologist, and a PsyAssoc member) but I'm confused as to the connections you're trying to make among them.   Your examples vary **greatly** in meaning (even to contradiction).   Which is the primary/most important role you want to convey and what is the secondary one?  Why does your audience care about these roles, especially the secondary and least important ones?

Comment: I edited the post to address your comment: 
- It is for a resume.
- the connection is that certified psycologists (the ones that can work as psycologists) are the one in the Psychologists Association. the association request as mandatory an internship of at least one year and then a final exam in order to be part of it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it is known that you must be a member of the Psychologist Association in order to participate in the internship, you might write

> I am doing the mandatory internship to become a certified psychologist

if not, then

> I am doing the mandatory internship to become a Psychologists Association certified psychologist.

or

> I am doing the Psychologists Association's mandatory internship to become a certified psychologist.

this assumes there might be more than one association offering certification.